# preg_match() fails with windows

Tags: php, regex

I need to check if a string contains a table, which is like this:

```
+--------+------+-------+
| <info>number</info> | <info>char</info> | <info>word</info>  |
+--------+------+-------+
| 1      | a    | alfa  |
| 2      | b    | beta  |
| 3      | c    | gamma |
+--------+------+-------+
```

I do not know the number of columns, nor the number of rows, but this is the structure of the table.

This regex works with Unix, but not with Windows

```
[\+\-]+[\r\n](\|(\s+<info>[^<]+<\/info>\s+\|)+)[\r\n](\+|\-)+[\r\n]((\|(\s+[^\|]+\s+\|)+[\r\n])+)(\+|\-)+
```

This is a test:
https://regex101.com/r/TSxSd7/1

And this is a part of code:

```
    $regexRowDivider = '[\+\-]+';
    $regexHeader = '(\|(\s+<info>[^<]+<\/info>\s+\|)+)';
    $regexRow = '\|(\s+[^\|]+\s+\|)+';
    $regexRows = '((' . $regexRow . '[\r\n])+)';
    $regexTable = $regexRowDivider . '[\r\n]' . $regexHeader . '[\r\n]' . $regexRowDivider . '[\r\n]' . $regexRows . $regexRowDivider;

    preg_match('/' . $regexTable . '/', $output, $matches);
```

After hours of testing, I can not figure out what the problem is. Do you have any idea? `preg_last_error()` returns a `0` (no errors)

Comment: Possibly because `[\r\n]` will match **one** instance of `\r` or `\n` whereas a Windows line terminator is both; i.e. `\r\n` - try changing that part of the pattern to `[\r\n]{1,2}`

Comment: Replace `[\r\n]` with `\R`

Comment: Use `[+-]+\R(\|(?:\s+<info>[^<]+<\/info>\s+\|)+)\R[+-]+\R((?:\|(?:\s+[^|]+\s+\|)+\R)+)[+-]+`

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys, the suggestion was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because you're only accepting one of either `\r` or `\n`, and Windows uses both (`\r\n`). You can match both of these newline characters (and more) by using `\R`.

I removed a few pieces of complexity, so it doesn't enforce spaces in every cell:

```
[+-]+\R+\|(\s*<info>[^<]+<\/info>\s*\|)+\R+[+-]+\R+\|([^|]+\|)+\R+[+-]+

\---/   \------------------------------/   \---/   \----------/   \---/
Line             Column Headers            Line      Contents     Line
```

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/TSxSd7/3)

Comment: Thank you @Addison, the suggestion was correct.
The complexity of the regex is due to the need to extract different contents from the table